# Creating ontology for INSPIRE data

Tags: inspire

I want to create ontology for the INSPIRE data.As the there is a large amount of data I wanted to know what technique should be used for that

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

An ontology should be built as part of a consensus of users with expertise in the domain of interest. The simple advice would be don't build your own, but rather use (and extend if necessary) an existing ontology

For tools to create/manage ontologies, try [poolparty](https://www.poolparty.biz/) or [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/products.php)